# Adding UIView overlay to KeyWindow without covering alerts

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm trying to add a loading overlay to my application, and so far it works ok except that it covers alerts for some reason.

- The overlay is a fullscreen UIView that gets shown as such:

  ```
  UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.AddSubview(view);
  ```
- The alerts I'm displaying afterwards are created as such:

  ```
  var alertController = UIAlertController.Create(title, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

  alertController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext;

  viewController.PresentViewController(alertController, true, null);
  ```

The problem is that the alerts are displayed below the overlay despite having ModalPresentationStyle set to OverCurrentContext. Is there a way to force them to be displayed on top of everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause:**
When you add subview on `keywindow`,the view will appear on the top of the screen.And the UIAlertController is still been added on `keywindow`.So it always on below of the view.
[image]

**Solution:**
If you do want to the alert on the top of anything .you can use the `UIAlertView` instead of `UIAlertController`.

```
var alertView = new UIAlertView("title","message",this,"OK",null);
alertView.Show();
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!